# Read multiple values from Angular $injector using array destructuring

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I have this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, CategoryService) {

  CategoryService.create = function () {
    return Promise.resolve({});
  };

  const $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
  const $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
  const $templateCache = $injector.get('$templateCache');

}));
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do something like this:

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, CategoryService) {

  CategoryService.create = function () {
    return Promise.resolve({});
  };

  const [$compile, $rootScope, $templateCache] = $injector.get('$compile','$rootScope','$templateCache');

}));
```

Comment: How about `const [$compile, $rootScope, $templateCache] = ['$compile', '$rootScope', '$templateCache'].map(svc => $injector.get(svc))`

Comment: nice that would work, feel free to add answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

And I also logged the methods on $injector:

```
'$injector =>', Object{invoke: function invoke(fn, self, locals, serviceName) { ... }, instantiate: function instantiate(Type, locals, serviceName) { ... }, get: function getService(serviceName, caller) { ... }, annotate: function (fn) { ... }, has: function (name) { ... }, strictDi: false}
```

does not look like there is a way to do that. Probably because array destructuring still requires transpilation in most browsers?

So you can create a helper function to do this:

```
  const myInjector = $injector => {
    return function(){
      return Array.from(arguments).map(function(a){
        return $injector.get(a);
      })
    }
  };
```

and use it like so:

```
const inj = myInjector($injector);
const [AcqService, RolesService] = inj('AcqService', 'RolesService');
```